# Porque a somas esta retornando 0 e só funciona quando coloco as variáveis como locais?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

quando coloco a var n1,n2 e a s dentro da function somar, só ai que o resultado aparece certo!porque?  Sou iniciante.

```
/*variaveis dos elelentos html*/
var dr1= document.querySelector('input#txtn1')
var dr2= document.querySelector('input#txtn2')
var botao = document.querySelector('button.so')
var r = document.querySelector('div.res')

/*recebe os valores digitados no input*/
var n1= Number(dr1.value)
var n2 = Number(dr2.value)
/*realizar a soma dos valores do input*/
var s = n1 + n2
/*cria um evento para ser chamado*/
botao.addEventListener("click",somar)

function somar(){

    r.innerHTML = s
    r.style.color = 'red'
}
```

Comment: Do comentário `/*recebe os valores digitados no input*/` até o comentário `/*cria um evento para ser chamado*/` mova para primeira linha da função `soma()`.

Comment: é simples, quando executa o código guarda os valores da variáveis, e se mudar não são atualizadas. Se quer pegar os valores atualizados tem que colocar o código na função soma como o @AugustoVasques comentou. Faça um debug e vais perceber isso facil ;)

Comment: Vlw, então é recomendado colocar as variáveis de conversão  e de operação dentro da função como variáveis locais? e quando devo ou não usar como variável global teria um exemplo ou alguma referencia bibliografia sobre isso?

Comment: *"é recomendado colocar as variáveis de conversão e de operação dentro da função como variáveis locais"* não tem a ver com ser recomendado, só que **é preciso que seja local** pq precisa pegar o valor atualizado, mas uma ideia mais ampla é sempre usar variável local, a global é excessão, só use se **realmente precisar**

Comment: O vlw, agradeço de verdade, abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Você esta executando a soma antes mesmo do evento ser disparado, a soma esta sendo executada quando a página carrega, e neste momento provavelmente os inputs estão vazios

Quando você usa o click a soma JÁ FOI EXECUTADA, então basta mover tudo pra dentro da função:

```js
/*variaveis dos elelentos html*/
var dr1= document.querySelector('input#txtn1')
var dr2= document.querySelector('input#txtn2')
var botao = document.querySelector('button.so')
var r = document.querySelector('div.res')

botao.addEventListener("click",somar)

function somar(){

    /*recebe os valores digitados no input*/
    var n1= Number(dr1.value)
    var n2 = Number(dr2.value)
    /*realizar a soma dos valores do input*/
    var s = n1 + n2
    /*cria um evento para ser chamado*/

    r.innerHTML = s
    r.style.color = 'red'
}
```

```html
<input id="txtn1"> + <input id="txtn2"> = <div class="res"></div>
<button type="button" class="so">Somar</button>
```